# Repeat previous square bracket command

Tags: cursor-motions, repeated-commands

I am using the `]` commands (e.g. `]]`) a lot and have a bunch of custom ones too.

Is there a command that repeats the last such command, similar to how `.` repeats the last edit?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, though you can lean on vim-repeat by tpope to use `.` for this (requires setting up some custom maps, IIRC)